# Creating Primary key from 2 autonumber and constant letter when creating table

Tags: mysql

I am new to MYSQL and would like to create a table where a constant Letter depicting the department is added to an auto increment number. This way I would be able to identify the category of the worker upon viewing the ID. 
Ex. Dept A and employee 135. The ID I am imaging should read A135 or something similar. I have created the table, the auto increment works fine, the constant letter has been declared and is featuring. However I would like to concatenate them  in order to use the A135 as a primary key.

Any Help Please?

Answer (score 0):

This quite tricky, and you would be probably better off doing manual concatenation in a select query.

But since you asked for it...

In normal usage you would have used a computed column for this, but they do not support using autoincremented columns in their declaration. So you would need to use triggers:

- on insert, query `information_schema.tables` to retrieve the autoincremented id that is about to be assigned and use it to generate the custom id
- on update, reset the custom id

Consider the following table structure:

```
create table workers (
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    name varchar(50) not null,
    dept varchar(1) not null,
    custom_id varchar(12) 
);
```

Here is the trigger for insert:

```
delimiter //
create trigger trg_workers_insert before insert ON workers
for each row
begin

    if new.custom_id is null then
        select auto_increment into @nextid 
        from information_schema.tables
        where table_name = 'workers' and table_schema = database();

        set new.custom_id = CONCAT(new.dept, lpad(@nextid, 11, 0));
    end if;
end
//
delimiter ;
```

And the trigger for update:

```
delimiter //    
create trigger trg_workers_update before update ON workers
for each row
begin
    if new.dept is not null then        
        set new.custom_id = CONCAT(new.dept, lpad(old.id, 11, 0));
    end if;
end
//                                            
delimiter ;
```

Let's run a couple of inserts for testing:

```
insert into workers (dept, name) values ('A', 'John');
insert into workers (dept, name) values ('B', 'Jim');
select * from workers;

| id  | name | dept | custom_id    |
| --- | ---- | ---- | ------------ |
| 1   | John | A    | A00000000001 |
| 2   | Jim  | B    | B00000000002 |
```

And let's test the update trigger

```
update workers set dept = 'C' where name = 'Jim';
select * from workers;

| id  | name | dept | custom_id    |
| --- | ---- | ---- | ------------ |
| 1   | John | A    | A00000000001 |
| 2   | Jim  | C    | C00000000002 |
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9N64Qv6Svoqx6B5FXnnvdn/1)**

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, my answer does not fit in a comment.

I agree with @GMB. 
This is a tricky situation and in some cases (selects mainly) will lead in a performance risk due you'll have to split PK in where statements, which is not recommended.
Having a column for department and another for auto_increment is more logical. And the only gap you have is to know the number of employees per department you'll have to make a count grouping by dept. Instead of a max() splitting your concatenated PK, which is is at high performance cost.
Let atomic and logic data remain in separate columns. I would suggest to create a third column with the concatenated value.
If, for some company reason, you need B1 and A1 values for employees of different departments, I'd suggest to have 3 columns

```
Col1 - letter(not null)
Col2 - ID(Not auto-increment, but calculated as @GMB's solution) (Not NULL)
Col3 - Concatenation of Col1 and Col2 (not null)
PK( Col1, col2)
```